# ARM NEON how can i change value with a index

Tags: arrays, indexing, arm, simd, neon

```
unsigned char changeValue(unsigned char pArray[256],unsigned char value)
{


return pArray[value];
}
```

how can I change this function with neon with about uint8x8_t??

thanks for your help!!

Answer (score 1):

You can't - NEON does not have gathered loads. The only case that you can handle like this is when you want to return 8 or 16 contiguous byte values.